# Determining Color of a Voxel in Python

Tags: python, voxel, mri

I am working with MRI data and would like to determine the RGB value of a given voxel. Can anyone show me a clear way to do this? Thanks.

this must be something that's extremely easy to do because I haven't seen anyone clearly asking for it. I've done this with pixels obviously a million times but voxels are giving me trouble. Thanks.

Comment: MRIs don't have color information. The raw NMR data can be used to reconstruct some kind of spatial density conditioned on the relaxation time and pulse train in the RF coil, but any interpretation of that as "color" is application-dependent. Also, what format is your data in?

Comment: @nanofarad thank you for explaining this. Using nibabel to load .nii files into 4d numpy arrays. And the goal is to quantify the number of pixels beyond a certain RGB value threshhold for "black" based on an ROI so we would be treating the MRI as a regular 3d image/stack of 2D images (?) is there a logical way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not familiar with nibabel; I recommend [edit]ing that into the question to make it clearer to figure readers so they know what you currently have.